# Error using jQuery uploadify with IE

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Testing in IE 8 i get this error:  Object doesn't support this property or method
I'm using the latest release of uploadify.

It occurs in a custom javascript file I've included in the head section of my page. Here's the code:

```
$(function () {

        $('#fileupload').uploadify({                  // <--IE points to this line: Object doesn't support this property or method
            'uploader'  : 'flash/uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : 'includes/core/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg' : 'images/close.png',
            'auto'      : false,
            'folder'    : 'uploads',
            'multi'     : true,
            'onComplete' : function(){return false;}
        });
});
```

I've checked for anything in my markup that has an id of "settings" ...there's nothing. Can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

HTML Header:

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title><?php echo $_title ?> &#9679; Dashboard</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import url("css/style.css");
        @import url("css/jquery.wysiwyg.css");
        @import url("css/facebox.css");
        @import url("css/visualize.css");
        @import url("css/date_input.css");
                @import url("css/uploadify.css");
    </style>

    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("css/ie.css");</style><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.img.preload.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.filestyle.mini.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.date_input.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.visualize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.select_skin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pngfix.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML header?

Comment: Looks like uploadify.js isn't loaded. Could that be?

Comment: it should be, it's being included before my custom script and after jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object doesn't support this property or method" means that the thing you're trying to call or use doesn't exist or isn't available for the object.

It sounds like maybe you have done one of the following:

1. Not included the external js file that declares the `uploadify` method.
2. Mis-typed the path to the external js file.
3. Included the external js file before the jquery js file(s).

Try opening the page up in Firefox with Firebug. When you do that, you can check to make sure all scripts are loaded properly.

Comment: I've done all 3 and I can navigate to it in the browser but looking at the source code it's not included!!! I've cleared the cache and refreshed...it's still not including it??

Comment: Of course, my own stupid mistake...i was looking at the login page head section forgetting that it has it's own head section and isn't just included in the index.php file.